# changing getMap to GetMapAsync

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to create an interactive infoWindow based on one of the answers from Stack Overflow.
However, I am getting an error with `getMap()` used in the code. Although I've tried with `getMapAsync()`, I'm unable to resolve the problem. Please help me. If any new code is available for an interactive infowindow with a button, then please share the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewGroup infoWindow;
private TextView infoTitle;
private TextView infoSnippet;
private Button infoButton1, infoButton2;
private OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener infoButtonListener;

static final LatLng latlng1 = new LatLng(28.5355, 77.3910);
static final LatLng latlng2 = new LatLng(28.6208768, 77.3726377);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    final MapWrapperLayout mapWrapperLayout = (MapWrapperLayout)findViewById(R.id.map_relative_layout);
    final GoogleMap googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();

    // MapWrapperLayout initialization
    // 39 - default marker height
    // 20 - offset between the default InfoWindow bottom edge and it's content bottom edge
    mapWrapperLayout.init(googleMap, getPixelsFromDp(this, 39 + 20));

    // We want to reuse the info window for all the markers,
    // so let's create only one class member instance
    this.infoWindow = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);

    this.infoTitle = (TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
    this.infoSnippet = (TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.addressTxt);
    this.infoButton1 = (Button)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
    this.infoButton2 = (Button)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.btnTwo);

    // Setting custom OnTouchListener which deals with the pressed state
    // so it shows up
    this.infoButtonListener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(infoButton1, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_bg), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_bg)){
        @Override
        protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
            // Here we can perform some action triggered after clicking the button
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "click on button 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    this.infoButton1.setOnTouchListener(infoButtonListener);

    infoButtonListener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(infoButton2, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_bg),getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_bg)){
        @Override
        protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click on button 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
    infoButton2.setOnTouchListener(infoButtonListener);

    /*infoWindow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click on infowindow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });*/

    googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            // Setting up the infoWindow with current's marker info
            infoSnippet.setText(marker.getTitle());
            infoTitle.setText(marker.getSnippet());
            infoButtonListener.setMarker(marker);

            // We must call this to set the current marker and infoWindow references
            // to the MapWrapperLayout
            mapWrapperLayout.setMarkerWithInfoWindow(marker, infoWindow);
            return infoWindow;
        }
    });

    // Let's add a couple of markers
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latlng1)
            .title("Source")
            .snippet("Comapny Name")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latlng2)
            .title("Destination")
            .snippet("AmisunXXXXXX")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));

    //googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 15));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng1, 10));

}

public static int getPixelsFromDp(Context context, float dp) {
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int)(dp * scale + 0.5f);
}

}
```

The error is coming because Google has removed `getMap()`, but I dont know the alternative solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Define `private GoogleMap gMap`and implement `OnMapReadyCallback` in your main Activity and implement `onMapReady` method

in `onMapReady` you should write this line
`gMap = googleMap`, then you can do what you want in `onMapReady`

- getting current location
- custom setting for your map
- and ...

now it's time to use this lines in your `OnCreate` method

```
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

it should solve your problem, hope it helped you

Comment: i asks me to implement onMapReady, can u provide more code please?